# Good asymptotic for $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{p_n^{p_n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, prime-numbers, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

Consider

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{p_n^{p_n}}$$

Where $p_n$ is the $n$ th prime.

What is a very good asympotic $g(x)$ for this function as $x$ goes to $+\infty$ ?

I want at least

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty}   \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1$$

I know for sufficiently large $x$ we have

$$\exp(\ln(x)^{1+v}) \ll  f(x) \ll \exp(x^v)$$

for any fixed $v$ with $0<v$.
(The upper bound is easy to show using Stirling's approximation for the factorial and the Maclaurin series for $\exp(x)$. The lower bound is also quite easy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The estimate $\lim f(x)/g(x)=1$ might be too difficult to achieve given the known estimates of the $n$-th prime $p_n$. To see the results on the $n$-th prime, see [this](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL22/Axler/axler17.pdf).

Let $\epsilon>0$ be given.
We have $x^n/p_n^{p_n} = \exp(n\log x - p_n \log p_n)$.

Although precise asymptotic is out of reach, we may strengthen your lower and upper bounds using
$$
n\log^2 n\leq \ p_n\log p_n\leq (1+\epsilon) n\log^2 n
$$
for $n\geq N_{\epsilon}$ with effectively computable $N_{\epsilon}$.

For a lower bound, single term of the series when $n=\lceil \exp(\sqrt{(1-\epsilon)\log x})\rceil$ is by $\log n\sim \sqrt{(1-\epsilon)\log x}$ and $p_n\log p_n\leq (1+\epsilon)n\log^2 n$, we have
$$
n\log x -p_n\log p_n \geq \log x \cdot \exp(\sqrt{(1-\epsilon)\log x})
$$
$$
-(1-\epsilon^2)\log x \exp(\sqrt{(1-\epsilon)\log x})
$$
$$
\geq \epsilon^2 \log x \cdot \exp(\sqrt{(1-\epsilon)\log x})
$$
Thus, we have for sufficiently large $x$,
$$
\exp(\epsilon^2 \log x \cdot \exp(\sqrt{(1-\epsilon) \log x})\leq f(x).
$$
For an upper bound, we use $n\log^2 n\leq p_n\log p_n$ and we split the sum into two cases $n>\exp(\sqrt{(1+\epsilon)\log x})$ and $n\leq \exp(\sqrt{(1+\epsilon)\log x})$.

The former case, we have $(1+\epsilon)\log x < \log^2 n$ yielding
$$
\log x - \log^2 n < -\epsilon \log x.
$$
Then the sum over $n$ in this range is bounded by
$$
\sum_{n>\exp(\sqrt{(1+\epsilon)\log x})} x^{-\epsilon n}\leq 1/2
$$
using geometric series.

The latter case $n\leq \exp(\sqrt{(1+\epsilon)\log x})$, by applying upper bound of $e^{n\log x}$, the sum over this range is bounded by
$$
\exp(\log x \cdot \exp(\sqrt{(1+\epsilon)\log x})\sum_{N_{\epsilon}\leq n\leq \exp(\sqrt{(1+\epsilon)\log x})} \frac1{\exp(n\log^2 n)}
$$
The sum over $n$ is a convergent series. With suitable $N_{\epsilon}$, we can assume that the sum is $\leq 1/2$.

Therefore, we obtain an upper bound of $f(x)$ by combining the two sums:
$$
f(x)\leq \exp(\log x \cdot \exp(\sqrt{(1+\epsilon)\log x}).
$$

Putting these estimates together, we obtained
$$
\exp(\epsilon^2 \log x \cdot \exp(\sqrt{(1-\epsilon) \log x})
$$
$$
\leq f(x) \leq \exp(\log x \cdot \exp(\sqrt{(1+\epsilon)\log x}).
$$
The above estimates are in fact equivalent to a simpler expression. Given $\epsilon >0$, for sufficiently large $x$,
$$\exp(\exp(\sqrt{(1-\epsilon)\log x}))\leq f(x)\leq \exp(\exp(\sqrt{(1+\epsilon)\log x})).$$

Comment: Im sorry you lost me when you set $n$ as a function of $\ln(x)$. It is unclear to me. My fault probably but still ...

Comment: This came up after trying out several different functions. But, the main idea is to obtain a single term which has the size close to the upper bound.